# Event in RIA Service

Tags: c#, silverlight, wcf-ria-services

I have couple views in a Silverlight Business Application project and one domain service.

From first view, I want to be able to call a method on the service which is easy enough to do.
On the service, I want to be able to raise an event when this method is called. In my second view, I want to have an event handler for this event on the service.

So far I have this for the service

```
public class MyService: DomainService
{
   public event EventHandler<EventArgs> MyEvent;

    public void SimulateSomeAction()
    {
        if(MyEvent!= null)
        {
            MyEvent(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
 }
```

And in the first view, I have

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MyServiceContext context = new MyServiceContext();
    context.SimulateSomeAction();
}
```

But for the second view, I don't see the event being exposed to be handled. If this is the wrong approach, How can this be achieved? I'm looking for some means to update the client view initiated by the service.

EDIT:

The two views I mention will be on different clients. Essentially I'm looking for a client-to-client communication solution via the domain service. If trying to do it via the domain service is a bad idea or not possible, please suggest as to what I should be looking into.

Currently looking into ["Pushing Data to a Silverlight Client with a WCF Duplex Service"](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2008/06/16/pushing-data-to-a-silverlight-client-with-wcf-duplex-service-part-i.aspx) but would love it if it's possible with RIA services.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature you're looking for is currently the top request on the [RIA Services Wish List](http://dotnet.uservoice.com/forums/57026-wcf-ria-services). From what I hear, people have been successful using the WCF Duplex Service, but I haven't seen an example.

Answer (score 0):

Are those code snippets accurate?

I don't see how your first view is seeing the Simulate method.

If you want to add functionality to the generated contexts or models, look at using a partial class.
So in the Silverlight project add a class like

```
namespace MyProject.Web.Services {
  public partial class MyContext {
    // Add new methods, events etc here
  }
}
```

Comment: The snippets are fairly accurate. I have replace the actual names with items like MyEvent etc., and that is the way RIA Domain service works. You add your functionality to the service and the client gets a context instance as a proxy.

Comment: So you added the event in the server project?

Comment: Try adding it in the silverlight project using the partial class example I gave.

Comment: I should probably edit my question but I'm not looking for a client side event. The two views I mention could be on different clients. Imagine if you will, a chat message sent from clientA using view1 to the server. I'm trying to figure out how to transmit that to ClientB in view2. It doesn't have to be an event.